# How to extend views in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a base.xml view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shown_path"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to create two more views:

view1.xml with a TextView and view2.xml with a Button (both "extending" base.xml).

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't extend but you can `<include>` a layout. Otherwise: Copy&paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't. you can only include a xml layout into another one ([include/merge](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html))